# Losing UIButton within a custom cell when reloading table

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, reload

I've custom `UITableViewCell`s where I placed buttons dynamically in code. I have programmatically set actions for such buttons, and when the action is triggered, then I need to reload the table, among other things. Once reload is called, the sender button disappears, and I don't know why... Could somebody give me a hint for the possible reason? If button is not tapped, and I scroll up and down through the table, it remains there.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is a code snippet from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSArray *listData =[self.tableViewEntries objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

   UITableViewCell *cell;

   if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: {
            cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCell"];
            ((CustomCell *)cell).cellTextField.tag = firstCellTag;
            cell.tag = firstCellTag;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondCell"];
            ((CustomCell *)cell).cellTextField.tag = secondCellTag;
            cell.tag = secondCellTag;
            break;
        }
   } 
   return cell;
}
```

The `CustomCell` I've defined is loaded from a `nib`. Those cells have a `UITextField` for user input and a `UIView` where I set or remove the buttons dynamically in code according to the user input within the text field. The buttons are created in code, and their actions are set in code as well:

```
- (void)setButtonForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withResult:(BOOL)isValid
{
   UIImage* validationButtonNormalImage = nil;
   UIImage* validationButtonHighlightImage = nil;

   UIButton *validationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [validationButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ((CustomCell *)cell).cellValidationView.frame.size.width, ((CustomCell *)cell).cellValidationView.frame.size.height)];

   if (isValid) {
       validationButtonNormalImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"success.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
       validationButtonHighlightImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"success.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

      [validationButton removeTarget:self
                            action:@selector(validationButtonTapped:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   }
   else {
       validationButtonNormalImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
       validationButtonHighlightImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

      [validationButton setTag:cell.tag];

      [validationButton removeTarget:self
                            action:@selector(validationButtonTapped:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      [validationButton addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(validationButtonTapped:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   }


   [validationButton setBackgroundImage:validationButtonNormalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [validationButton setBackgroundImage:validationButtonHighlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


   [((CustomCell *)cell).cellValidationView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
   [((CustomCell *)cell).cellValidationView addSubview:validationButton];
}
```

Then, in `validationButtonTapped:`, I do some tasks and call to `[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:NO];`, and there is when I loose the button from the view. However, if I don`t tap the button and I scroll down and up again to get 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:' called again, the button remains here. It is like I only loose it when calling for a reload.

Any help?

Comment: can you please post your code...?

Answer (score 0):

Cells are usually reused if you are following the usual `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` pattern. Do you remove all subviews in prepareForReuse for each cell? If you didn't then you would see unexpected buttons on cells as you scroll up and down. You probably need to add the buttons as required in each cell's configuration *after* you get the cell for reuse (or in newer code, dequeue a cell) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I understand... since I'm creating the button in code and adding it to the cell like this: `[myCustomcell addSubview:button];`, how could I retain this button? Or should I have strong properties for them?

Comment: Yeah you should have strong properties for buttons to retain it